# Django Test Run Environment error: no enough space left on disk

Tags: python, django

I was going through a [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/),
I was able to execute through the following steps [creating a project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project), [database setup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup)
the problem raised in [development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server) step.

I tried  `(venv)$ python manage.py runserver` in virtual environment

output:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

January 14, 2015 - 09:39:53
Django version 1.7.2, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[2015-01-14 09:39:54,347 pyinotify ERROR] add_watch: cannot watch /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py WD=-1, Errno=No space left on device (ENOSPC)
[2015-01-14 09:39:54,348 pyinotify ERROR] add_watch: cannot watch /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/test/__init__.py WD=-1, Errno=No space left on device (ENOSPC)
```

To check whether my partition disk is out of space I did tried

```
(venv) $ df
```

output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      236182272 56881792 167280052  26% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1969912        4   1969908   1% /dev
tmpfs             397084     1480    395604   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1985416     3048   1982368   1% /run/shm
none              102400       28    102372   1% /run/user
```

I could clearly see few free space in the available section.

Have anybody had this error before while trying to runserver in Django.

Comment: You may have run out of inodes. Check `df -i`

Comment: I tried the command     $ df -i
    
    
    Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/sda1      15007744 469320 14538424    4% /
    none             496354      2   496352    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev             492478    558   491920    1% /dev
    tmpfs            496354    599   495755    1% /run
    none             496354      1   496353    1% /run/lock
    none             496354     10   496344    1% /run/shm
    none             496354     20   496334    1% /run/user

Comment: looks fine, no other ideas sorry.

Comment: You can check this github link : https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You may have reached your quota of watches.

To **find your current limit**, type this in your terminal:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Which is typically 8192 by default.

To **increase your limit**, type this:

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=16384
```

Then restart django.

To **permanently set this limit**, type this:

```
echo 16384 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

There's a very detailed answer, where you'll find more info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13757/79648

Comment: can it cause any problems to other django apps, or any other apps hosted on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/cleaning-up-a-ubuntu-gnulinux-system-updated-with-ubuntu-14-10-and-more-tools-added.html) link.

Basically what worked for me was that I used the first 3 commands:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And then I restarted my development server, and I wasn't seeing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
$virtualenv-3.4 -p /usr/bin/python3.4 venv 
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.4
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in venv/bin/python3.4
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

workingdirectory

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Again I installed Django.

```
(venv)$ python manage.py runserver
       Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 15, 2015 - 18:56:44
Django version 1.7.2, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

It was pretty neat with no PyNotify error